# Problems with Parallel.js/WebWorker and optimized code

Tags: javascript, requirejs, rjs, optimization

I'm using rjs optimizer via grunt. I want to use webworker using the 
Parallel.js lib, but I get syntax errors running the optimized code.

**Comparison of optimized and unoptimized code:**

See this gist at github: 
https://gist.github.com/mwager/4123a3fd5577b630582b

As you cann see I want to use smt like `helper().importedHelperFunction1()`
inside the worker. This way it's easy to import helper functions to my worker code 
(see http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/#require).

The real problem is syntax error because of the optimized variable- 
and function-names. Syntax error in chrome dev tools is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

which has problems with the `function () {` in line 2 of the gist.

In the optimized code the helpers stuff looks like this:

`f=function(){return{importedHelperFunction1:function(a,b){return a+b}}}`

But Parallel.js requires named functions to import into workers:

```
var webworkerHelpers = function helper() { // <-- named! but not after optimization )-:
    return {
        importedHelperFunction1: function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
...
```

So it will import the function like this:

```
function() { return { importedHelperFunction1: ...
```

which leads to the syntax error...

I'm doing smt like this:

```
var theWorker = new Parallel(workerData);
theWorker.require(webworkerHelpers);
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the best way to handle this kind of problem? Should I quit using Parallel js? Or is there any option in the optimizer to "don't remove function names?". Sorry, just cannot get this to work...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe I should consider another (better) way of importing my helper functions...

I wanted to import this way because of legacy browser support, so if webworker support is not available (e.g. IE9) I could just call the function which should be passed in side the worker as normally and then use `helper().someFn()` there too...

Comment: you could try using https://github.com/icodeforlove/task.js, and globals